# Pandas - how to get the minimum value for each row from values across several rows

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in the following structure:

```
|index | a  | b  |  c |  d | e  |
| ---- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- |
|0     | -1  | -2|  5 |  3 | 1  |
```

How can I get the minimum value for each row using only the *positive* values in columns a-e?

For the example row above, the minimum of (5,3,1) should be 1 and not (-2).

Comment: `df[['a','b','c','d','e']].clip(lower=0).min(axis=1)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang: ```clip``` sets the lower threshold to be 0, which also becomes the minimum value. However, this 0 does not exist in any of the columns.

Comment: That’s true. Then you can use `df.where[df>0].min(1)`

Comment: Clarification use `df.where(df>0).min(axis=1)` Paranthesis not square brackets.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang with Scott's modification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the loop on all rows and apply your condition on the rows.

for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"a":-2,"b":2,"c":5},{"a":3,"b":0,"c":-1}])

#   a   b   c
#0  -2  2   5
#1  3   0   -1

def my_condition(li):
    li = [i for i in li if i>=0]
    return min(li)

min_cel = []
for k,r in df.iterrows():
    li = r.to_dict().values()
    min_cel.append( my_condition(li) )
    
df["min"] = min_cel

#   a   b   c   min
#0  -2  2   5   2
#1  3   0   -1  0
```

You can also write the same code on one line:

```
df['min'] = ddd.apply(lambda row: min([i for i in row.to_dict().values() if i>=0]) , axis=1)
```